# Combining modular relations

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

In my studies, I have encountered the following pair of modular relations

$$ \frac{n(n+2)}{4} \pmod{n+1} $$
$$ \frac{3(n+1)(3n+1)}{4} \pmod{3n+2} $$

As I am working over only the integers, the first relation only makes sense for $n \equiv 0 \mod 2$, while the second applies only for $n \equiv 1 \mod 2$. How can I combine these two relations into a single function? In other words, can the function

$$ c(n) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{n(n+2)}{4} \pmod{n+1} & n \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \\
\frac{3(n+1)(3n+1)}{4} \pmod{3n+2} & n \equiv 1 \pmod 2
\end{cases}
$$

be simplified to

$$ c(n) = p(n) \pmod{q(n)} $$

for some finite polynomials $p(n)$ and $q(n)$? My guess is yes, and that $p(n)$ is some quartic polynomial while $q(n)$ is quadratic, but I have no clue how to actually find them.